# Perl - customize log files for displaying only specific errors

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, we have a log file similar to below:

```
SQL> @D:\Luntbuild_Testing\ASCMPK\Files\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\FILES\DDL\20120412_152632__1_CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK.DDL
SQL> CREATE TABLE CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK
  2  (
  3  EVENT_CODE  VARCHAR2(4) ,
  4  ACC_ROLE  VARCHAR2(20)
  5  )
  6  ;
CREATE TABLE CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> @D:\Luntbuild_Testing\ASCMPK\Files\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\FILES\DDL\20120412_173845__2_CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK.DDL
SQL> DROP TABLE  CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK;

Table dropped.
```

Now I need a script to display only the script paths that have ORA-XXX errors, script should display only the path of the SQL> @D:\Luntbuild_Testing\ associated with ORA-xxx errors, I have tried below can you please help me to enhance the same.

```
$file = 'c:\data.txt';
open(txt, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
print "$line" if $line =~ /> @/; #here i want the output to display the path of the script with only ORA-xxx errors and ignore if there are no errors
print "$line" if $line =~ /ORA-/;
}
close(txt);
```

Comment: It will be great if your show exact input and desired output.

Comment: Input would be from a log file as shown above i will read the log file, 
output i need is as below 

SQL> @D:\Luntbuild_Testing\ASCMPK\Files\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\FILES\DDL\20120412_152632__1_CLTM_EVENT_ACC_ROLE_BLOCK.DDL 
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 

SQL> @D:\Luntbuild_Testing\ASCMPK\Files\Upgrade-Scripts\POST_113\Typ\misd_typ.sql 
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of immediately printing the line when you see the `> @` marker, store it in a variable, and only print it out if and when you actually see an error:

```
$file = 'c:\data.txt';
open(txt, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
$fn = $line if $line =~ /> @/; #here i want the output to display the path of the script with only ORA-xxx errors and ignore if there are no errors
print $fn, $line if $line =~ /ORA-/;
}
close(txt);
```

Also: it's good practice to write `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script.  `use strict;` forces you to explicitly name your local variables with `my`, which catches a lot of errors due to misspellings.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something pretty similar to what you tried:

```
$file = 'c:\data.txt';
open(F, $file);
my $last_cmd = '';
while (<F>) {
  $last_cmd = $_ if /^SQL\> \@D:/;
  print $last_cmd if /^ORA-/;
}
```